# Move file from tmp to documents using react-native-fs

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fs

I'm trying to move a file selected from a document picker to the Document Directory using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) and [react-native-document picker](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker).

However, I get the error below:

```
Error: “file name.mp3” couldn’t be moved to “Documents” because either the former doesn't exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn't exist.
```

What am I doing wrong?

FYI, I'm using iOS.

```
openDocumentPicker() {
  DocumentPicker.show({
    filetype: ['public.audio'],
  },(error,url) => {
    console.log(url);
    this.saveAudio(url);
  });

}

saveAudio(url) {

  var destPath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/' + 'name';

  RNFS.moveFile(url, destPath)
    .then((success) => {
      console.log('file moved!');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've found the error. The issue was that the file I was uploading had a space in it. I needed to decode the URL first before uploading, like so:

`var decodedURL = decodeURIComponent(url)`

Then I could move the file over.

`RNFS.copyFile(decodedURL, destPath)`

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me when destination folder doesn't exist.

```
[tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'error!', { [Error: The file “source.jpg” doesn’t exist.]
```

It's a wrong error message from [`react-native-fs`](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs). It should tell **target path folder not exists**.